# need help getting desired shrinkwrap functionality

Tags: shrinkwrap, blender-osm

I have a basemap and 3D building geometry from the OpenStreetMaps add-on.

To increase the realism of the scene, I've used the 3D building geometry and Knife Project to cut out the roofs of the buildings from the basemap.

Now I want to shrinkwrap the roofs to the buildings so it looks like they are more real.

Basically I have a mesh of polygons of cut out roofs, and directly under them in the z-direction are the roofs from the 3D building geometry. I just want to slide the cut outs down until they rest on the 3D buildings.

No matter what I do it seems to warp them and stretch them to multiple buildings, perhaps of some kind of distance tolerance?

Can anyone please show me how to achieve this? My meshes look like this:

[image]
[image]

and this is what I'm trying to get it to look like (basemap right on roof of buildings):

[image]

Since the buildings are all slightly different heights, the idea came to use Shrinkwrap Modifier. But no matter what I do, it seems to warp the original mesh when stretching it over the target mesh.

[image]

Both meshes share a common set of x and y points. I just want to slide down the cut outs until the z is the exact same, thus lining up with the actual buildings.

Comment: Have you tried the wrap method as Project and define the axis as Z?

Comment: @Psyonic yes I have and it leads to a weird result where some faces are shrinkwrapped but some dont move from their original position, making it jagged

Comment: try using a smooth modifier with a very low value before the shrinkwrap. It will shrink the meshes just a little bit so they will project on faces rather than vertices. But honestly this looks like a XY problem. You can add a new material for the roof of your buildings objects, set the UV to project from view and use the same material as the satellite plane